# How to fix Flow error when accessing a field with default value on an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

## Example

[Flow REPL](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gFSgCGAzqAEoCmRAxnpFrKqAORbV0sDciilAHplygcAT3SVQABUboyAXlABvRAF8eiMRNABlHERyTFK9bxrRSZAGLJolACrtJAwwDsAJmSq0cAOgDCTJiulK44ADwysHIANLr6hgB8yoigoCQJyDSg7pSQRACu0DhRcqDGqaCqvGnosiQAXNL1GrWMAEZ2zIoAFERYAOZNSuyQANKUok0ZWMiuA6rlyqoAlOXJKmlpNLCuGcqjE6JLbHkscb6X7BmLiv0DPFug7DgFWK4pT2kA2oeTALoNe6-PJHf4xSpPS6+a44SFVR4ImrPUK5LA9NabLYvN4fHrwtLhdzIABuiQJoHCwGJZPhK0R1WqfEE2DwuXyRTwNjsjkolB4QA)

## Problem

I'm trying to access a field on an object that I believe *should* always exist.

How can the following flow error be resolved?

## Snippet

```
problem = (arg: {refKey: string} = {}) => {
  const {refKey = 'ref', ...rest} = arg;
  return {
    [refKey]:arg[refKey],
    ...rest
  };
};
```

## Error:

```
19:       [refKey]:arg[refKey],
                       ^ Cannot get `arg[refKey]` because property `ref` is missing in object type [1].
References:
16:   problem = (arg: {refKey: string} = {}) => {
                      ^ [1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because you are setting the value when you are declaring it.

If you want to set a default value, you can set it in the default parameter, like so:

```
problem = (arg: {refKey: string} = {refKey: 'ref'}) => {
  const {refKey, ...rest} = arg;
  return {
    [refKey]:arg[refKey],
    ...rest
  };
};
```

**EDIT**

Okay, I think I misunderstood the problem and have now understood it (!).

If the default property will be named `'ref'`, you can do this:

```
problem = (arg: {refKey: string, ref: any} = {}) => {
  const {refKey = 'ref', ...rest} = arg;
  return {
    [refKey]:arg[refKey],
    ...rest
  };
};
```

Comment: This, however, creates another problem. Flow no longer complains, but if the user passes an object as an argument and that object doesn't have a `refKey` field, then `refKey` would have lost its default value of `ref`.

Comment: And adding that default value back causes the same flow error! `const {refKey = 'ref', ...rest} = arg;`

Comment: From what I understand, the `refKey` will have the name of a property in the args object? If so, my edit should work now.